# MS Access multiple Counters on SwitchBoard Form DCount error

Tags: ms-access

I would like to add counters on my main SwitchBoard form for each of section, and nothing worked for me so far with DCount and Count and qryNew..
Form itself doesn't have any Record Source it works with Commands,  there are table and qry for each of sections, can I achieve my goal with Dcount family function without adding Source to form? I actually need 3 data Sources then for each of table (or qry's).
This is how my setup works, I search all examples, played with all flavors of Double quotes, square brackets, Count, DCount and  Count(NewID!qryNewList), nothing worked for me .

I think main question is : can I refer to tbl to Access db with Empty Record Source on form ?

```
=DCount([NewID],[tblNew])
```

my Setup ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`DCount` expects strings for its arguments.

If you want your text box to display the number of rows contained in tblNew, use this as the text box's Control Source:

```
=DCount("*", "tblNew")
```

In this case, the text box Control Source is independent of the form's Record Source --- so it won't matter if the Record Source is not assigned.

Comment: Thanks much HUP!!!! it worked, sorry I tried to get +1 on your reply but it bounced back to 0, not sure what is wrong. Best. K